# Suggest me a standard way to express this statement

Tags: sentence

Suggest me a standard way to express this statement:

> "When I was fourteen, for the first time in my life I got to see how a
> computer looked like till then we had only heard rumor about computer.
>
> It was 2007, when my father promised to buy me a computer if I get
> good grades in School.
>
> Finally I got my own computer and precarious
> 28kbps of dial up internet.
>
> Since then it has been my foremost
> interest to play with it."

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This is not a writers workshop, nor an editing service, though we can help you work through specific questions about grammar or usage. Please take the site [tour] and review the [help] for a better understanding of how this site operates.

Comment: 'Suggest me ...' is non-standard, as [this answer on ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/3694/suggest-me-or-suggest-to-me) points out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I found no glaring mistakes with the sentences, I would suggest minor (or may be insignificant) changes.

*When I was fourteen, for the first time in my life, I saw how a computer looked like, and till that moment we (I) had only been hearing the rumors about computers.*

or,

*When I was fourteen, for the first time in my life, I saw how a computer looked like; prior to that we (I) had heard only the rumors about computers.*

*It was 2007, when my father promised to buy me a computer, if I got good grades in School.*

*Finally, I got my own computer and the precarious 28kbps of dial up internet.*

*Since then playing with it has been my foremost interest.*